# Unable to read django table in admin or through API

Tags: django, postgresql, model

I've added few tables to django app, and two of them are acting weird(all the other tables are working fine). I'm unable to read these 2 tables through django admin or postman API however, I'm able to read these table through postgres(pg admin). I'm getting index error in django-admin and postman on these two tables(or django models). These tables has data in them as verified using pgAdmin.

On further digging I found that I'm unable to see the query for these model objects.

```
> queryset    = MixDesigns.objects.all() 
> print(queryset.query)
  *** TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The tables are stored in postgres, and the DB is connected to django application. Any idea why this could be happening and possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your database settings in your Django settings file and make sure that they are correct

You can also try running the following command to check if there are any issues with your models:

```
   python manage.py check
```

There could be several reasons why this is happening. One possible reason is that the db connection is not configured correctly.
Check your db configuration in  settings.py if it is correct.

Also do check your admin.py if you have initialised the table to admin panel

Comment: Thanks for replying. So all the other tables are working fine in the same database so it seems the DB settings are fine. Its just these two particular tables that I'm unable to access through the app.